# !isValid not accepting any value from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

Right now the !isValid is not accepting any values in the input for current balance. Is there another way to verify the value in the input? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to0namiSB/QVCHT/5/)

The function in question:

```
    function isValid(entry, a, b)

        {
          if (isNaN(entry.value) || (entry.value==null) || (entry.value=="") || (entry.value < a) || (entry.value > b)) {
          alert("Invalid entry. Your min payment should be between " + a + " and " + b + ".")
                return false
           }
                return true
         }


    // send entries to validation function
    // exit if not valid
        if (!isValid(currentBalance, 0, 10000)) {
            return false
         } else if (!isValid(interest, 0, 30)) {
            return false
         } else {
            return true;
         }

         if (!isValid(mnth_pay, currentBalance*.02, currentBalance)) {
            return false
       } else {
            console.log("do nothing");
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVCHT/6/).
As I first added console.msg to get the values handled by the function isValid(entry, a, b), I noticed that entry.value is undefined, but entry matches the current input.
Adjusting to

```
  function isValid(entry, a, b)
  {
      if (isNaN(entry) || (entry==null) || (entry=="") || (entry < a) 
      || (entry.value > b))
      {... }
  }
```

seems to fix the issue.